# Tools for sorting/filtering based on map state

Tags: leaflet, software-recommendations, geonames, gisgraphy

I'm about to embark on a project that list restaurants on a map.

The restaurants will be in a list beneath a map. The list will be refreshed based on the map zooming. The map will also have selectable/hoverable bounding boxes, so the user can select a location (London) and then drill down on the location to get neighbourhoods/boroughs in that area (Westminster, Clapham etc.)

I'm looking at the following tools for the job - Gisgraphy (for data), OpenStreetMap (for maps and data) and leafletjs (for the boxes). I've looked into GeoServer but this seems to be something I can't host locally.

Is there anything I'm missing, or are there any better tools to achieve this?

Also are there any examples I could look at where this has been done already?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you need is a multi level spatial data access. Well these can be acheived by leaflet/openlayers.

For OpenLayers:
check filter examples, [cluster](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html). [bbox](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-bbox.html). See documentation [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy-js.html).

Also you are using OSM data and openlayers have pretty good in serving OSM tiles.

For Leaflet:

you can find about Leaflet clustering [here](http://leafletjs.com/2012/08/20/guest-post-markerclusterer-0-1-released.html). I find it more fancy than OpenLayers but for dont know how stable it is because its recent and OpenLayers is very old and thus more stable. But no offense you need to test it and see the outcome and that is how all open source libraries are developed.

You can see a GSE post on leaflet animated clustering [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17250/how-to-create-animated-cluster-markers-in-openlayers-leaflet)